# Cannot extending both ListActivity and AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, extends

Since java does not support multiple inheritance I have a problem getting this to work.

This is what I want to do :

```
public class CallForwardActivity extends ListActivity /* This is there I want to extend AsyncTask */ implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener
{

... // creating and initializing stuff

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    userInfo = this.getSharedPreferences(USERINFO_FILE, 0);
    userInfo.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
    userControl = new UserController(context);
    ListView lv = getListView();
    lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    //setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.callforward_items, R.id.callforward_item_text, callforwardLabels));

    list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

    callForwardList = new SimpleAdapter( 
            this, 
            list,
            R.layout.callforward_items,
            new String[] { "line1","line2" },
            new int[] { R.id.callforward_item_text, R.id.callforward_number } );



    populateList();
    setListAdapter( callForwardList );

    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        CustomDialog(); // this will make the asynchronous task call if the user presses "OK" within the dialog box.
    }

  });

}
```

How do I go about making the call asynchronous without extending AsyncTask ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create another class that extends `AsyncTask` and use it in your `ListActivity`. You can make it inner if you like. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

errrmmm.... there's no way you can extend two classes in java you can implement many interfaces but extend one class. you should create another say inner class which extends AsyncTask<..,..,..> and do your background jobs there.

More on multiple inheritance in java
http://java.sys-con.com/node/37748

Answer (score 0):

What is use case you are trying to use activity extending a asynctask, asynctask is used for background process, Acitivity component is used to provide UI

You are trying UIThread extends BackgroundThread, which means you are making a relationship like **'UIThread is-a BackgroundThread'**.

I feel there is another way to solve your use case.